# How do I import latitude/longitude into geofield?

Tags: importing-exporting, location

I have a CSV file with a id column, a latitude and a longitude column, and some other data in each record.  I have created a content type to hold this dataset. Each record will be mapped to a content.  I used [Geofield](http://drupal.org/project/geofield) to store the location.  How do I import the CSV file and create these contents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Feeds](http://drupal.org/project/feeds) module to import your csv file and map it to your content type.