# Machine readable coordinates to Geofield

Tags: location

I got a long txt file full of cordinates. Like this for every line;

```
 {"RT**n":"*****","RT**o":"*******","WGS**_lat":"******","WGS**_lon":"******" }
```

There are numbers, I just hide them since this is just a example.
Anyway. I got a lot of these and it would take me forever to manually insert them. Is there any way to import these into D7 Leaflet Geofield?

Thanks

Comment: It would help if you could tell us where each part of this line should go, what is it's meaning in D7 Leaflet Geofield. I mean, [Geofield](https://www.drupal.org/project/geofield) holds latitude and longitude, as far as I know, and here you have 8 numbers that can change. You want to simply ignore the ones that does not fit? Or what?

Comment: Yeah right, I want only the long and latiude to be imported. I dont know whats the best soultion for that is

Answer (score 0):

This question is similar to the follosing, I recommend using the Feeds module: [How do I import latitude/longitude into geofield?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/66091/how-do-i-import-latitude-longitude-into-geofield)